# Missing LSP diagnostics from XO via null-ls for TypeScript

Tags: neovim, filetype-typescript, plugin-null-ls

I have been using the same Neovim config on my desktop and laptop computers for a while now (it's actually based on LazyVim, but I can reproduce the issue without it as well) without any problems.

Now that we have started incorporating TypeScript into our JavaScript project, I have noticed that the XO diagnostics I have previously set up through null-ls (and still work for JavaScript files) don't appear on my laptop for TypeScript files.

The strange thing is that the output of `:LspInfo`, `:NullLsInfo`, `:LspLog` and `:NullLsLog` looks perfectly fine. I've tried installing XO globally and locally as well, and the diagnostics didn't show up, but it runs perfectly well from the command line in both cases.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your configuration for xo and null-ls? I have been using Neovim with NvChad but I just have to run xo from the command line (instead of on save).

Comment: @user49605 I don't think that this comment section is necessarily the right place to ask, also, given that I don't use `NvChad` and `null-ls` has been archived since then I might not even be the right person to ask, but with a quick search for _"nvchad null-ls"_ I found this documentation page, which might help: https://nvchad.com/docs/config/format_lint To use it with `XO`, just enable the `builtins.diagnostics.xo` and `builtins.code_actions.xo` sources.

Answer (score 0):

I was really weirded out by this mysterious issue, but decided to keep investigating, so I put a print statement into the code of null-ls for debugging, and strangely enough after reading the output and pressing Enter to continue the missing diagnostics appeared to my great surprise!  This behavior wasn't consistent, but after a bit of experimenting I have managed come to the conclusion that it only works if I spend *enough* time reading the output, but doesn't, when I dismiss it too quickly. At first I thought that it might be some sort of weird race condition.

It turned out that the reason for it working on my desktop with identical config is simply a question of performance, as XO was timing out while checking TypeScript files on my laptop.

**TL;DR:**
I needed to extend or completely turn off (set to `-1`) the timeout for XO diagnostics in null-ls.

```lua
require("null-ls").builtins.diagnostics.xo.with({
  -- milliseconds
  timeout = 10000,
}),
```